# Expectation of non-negative random variable vs Truncated random variable

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

I want to show that E[X|X>t]>=E[X],

where X is discrete non-negative r.v, and t is positive deterministic value.

Some ideas?

Edit: >= instead of >

Comment: Is this really true ?

Comment: Perhaps you are really trying to show $\geq$?

Comment: @Dean : Try finding a counter-example.

Comment: @Michael I edit that X is discrete. Why does it matter if > or >= ?

Comment: @Surb I don't really know but intuitively I think it is. We are averaging on only on high values of X so the average is higher than averaging on all the values of X

Comment: @Dean : As far as I know, if $A\subset B$, there is no reason to have $\frac{1}{m(A)}\int_A f\geq \frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f$.

Comment: Let's take cube-1 that gets values 1-6 and take cube-2 that gets values 3-6. Which cube has a higher expectation?

Answer (score 1):

#### Hints on a counter-example to $E[X|X>t]>E[X]$

Let $t=1$.  Try to find a random variable $X$ for which the information $\{X>1\}$ does not tell us anything new.

#### Hints on proving $E[X|X>t]\geq E[X]$

We don't care what kind of random variable $X$ is. We only require that the expectations are well defined, we don't care whether or not $t$ or $X$ can take negative values.

1) Try proving that for any probability $p \in [0,1]$ we have:
$$ 5p + 7(1-p)\leq 7$$

2) Try proving that for any real numbers $a,b$ that satisfy $a\leq b$, and any probability $p\in[0,1]$, we have:
$$ap + b(1-p) \leq b$$

3) Try proving that $E[X|X>t]\geq t$.  Try proving a related inequality for $E[X|X\leq t]$.

Answer (score 1):

This is, I suppose, implicit in the hint sequence presented in Michael's answer.

All bets are off if $P(X>t)=0$.

Otherwise write $$EX=E[X|X>t]P(X>t) + E[X|X\le t]P(X\le t).$$  Thus the number $EX$ is an element of the closed convex hull of the two conditional expectations, that is of the  interval with those conditional expectations as endpoints. It is easy to check that $E[X|X\le t]\le t \le E[X|X>t]$ and hence to see which is the right-hand endpoint.